# How to compute row-wise comparison of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, row

I got a table with lots of point informations and I need to fill the position field after row wise comparison of the four fields before.

If the X- & Y-Coordinate is equal and also the ID_01, a comparison of ID_02 is required to assign "End" into the Position field for the lower ID_02 value, hence the row with value 35 and "Start" into the one with row equal 36 as its larger.

| X-Coordinate | Y-Coordinate | ID_01 | ID_02 | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45000 | 554000 | 15 | 35 | ? |
| 45000 | 554000 | 15 | 36 | ? |
| 94475 | 59530 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 94491 | 60948 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 94491 | 60948 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 94151 | 64480 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 94151 | 64480 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 95408 | 68694 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 95408 | 68694 | 1 | 4 |  |
| 94703 | 69961 | 1 | 4 |  |
| 94703 | 69961 | 1 | 5 |  |
| 93719 | 70786 | 1 | 5 |  |
| 93719 | 70786 | 1 | 6 |  |
| 95310 | 72044 | 1 | 6 |  |
| 95310 | 72044 | 1 | 7 |  |
| 99525 | 82049 | 1 | 7 |  |
| 99525 | 82049 | 1 | 8 |  |
| 101600 | 84306 | 1 | 8 |  |
| 102744 | 85032 | 1 | 9 |  |
| 101600 | 84306 | 1 | 9 |  |
| 102744 | 85032 | 1 | 10 |  |
| 104155 | 86535 | 1 | 10 |  |
| 104575 | 86430 | 1 | 11 |  |

How would you handle in a pandas dataframe for instance?

Comment: Can you update your dataframe with more rows, please?

Comment: sure, i added a few more lines !

Comment: In the provided date there are no more than two rows with identical values for ['X-Coordinate', 'Y-Coordinate', 'ID_01']. Is  it always the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask. First sort your values by `ID_02` then check duplicated values. The position with row set to `True` has the `End` position, the other the `Start` position:

```
m = df.sort_values('ID_02').duplicated(['X-Coordinate', 'Y-Coordinate', 'ID_01'])

df['Position'] = np.where(m, 'End', 'Start')
print(df)

# Output
   X-Coordinate  Y-Coordinate  ID_01  ID_02 Position
0         45000        554000     15     35    Start
1         45000        554000     15     36      End
```

Comment: Nice, however it seems to me that the result might not be the expected one in case there are more than two rows with identical values for `['X-Coordinate', 'Y-Coordinate', 'ID_01']`,

Comment: @hpchavaz. That's why I asked to OP more rows.

Comment: @Olli. Did you check my answer? Does it work for you?